# Shared library libbar.so static linking to libfoo.a, program linking to libbar.so and libfoo.so, what happens?

Tags: c++, linker, global-variables, shared-libraries, static-libraries

(Hopefully this doesn't get too complicated...)

I've built a third-party C++ library `libfoo` with both static (`libfoo.a`) and shared (`libfoo.so`) versions. The object files were created with -fPIC. `libfoo` has several global variables that are used to configure its behavior, and functions that rely on these globals, for simplicity function `func1()` which interacts with variable `global_a`.

I have built my C++ shared library `libbar` that I've statically linked to `libfoo.a`. This is done without the --whole-archive option. So I believe `libbar.so` includes all the symbols and definitions it needs from `libfoo.a`. This library calls functions from `libfoo` which uses global variables to control behavior. In this case, let's say it calls function `func1()`.

Finally, I have a C++ client program `baz` that dynamically links to both `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so`. This client also uses the same functions/global variables from `libfoo`. It modifies `global_a` and calls `func1()`.

In general, what will be the behavior of the client `baz` in this scenario? Is this sort of configuration something I should avoid, or is it OK? And what would happen if `libfoo.a` and `libfoo.so` are different versions?

For the global variables I was sort of expecting that the code in `libbar.so` would use its own copies, and any changes in `baz` would modify the copies in `libfoo.so`, but that's not what I see. When `baz` modifies `global_a`, the effect is seen in `libbar.so`. There wasn't any other abnormal behavior from client `baz` that I could tell.

I also tried linking `baz` with `libfoo.a`, and see the same (apparently correct) behavior.

Valgrind in either case has no shown any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In general, what will be the behavior of the client baz in this scenario?

*In general*, the behavior of shared libraries on UNIX / ELF systems is intended to mimic that of archive libraries.

In particular, if your binary `baz` links against both `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so`, both of which *export* `global_a`, then the first definition wins. That is, all references to `global_a` from `baz`, `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so` will bind to the first instance found in the link order (presumably `libfoo.so` here).

This behavior can be modified by hiding symbols with e.g. `-fvisibility-hidden`, with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` or with a linker script.

You can see what is *exported* by each library with

```
nm -AD libfoo.so libbar.so | grep global_a
```

(this command will only show exported symbols).

> For the global variables I was sort of expecting that the code in libbar.so would use its own copies

That expectation is incorrect.

> Is this sort of configuration something I should avoid, or is it OK?

This is something you should generally avoid, because e.g. updating `libbar.so` without also relinking `libfoo.so` may produce inconsistency. Suppose the type of `global_a` changes in a later revision from `int` to `double`. All of a sudden a simple statement like:

```
global_a = 0.0;
```

inside `libbar.so` may now corrupt an unrelated variable that follows `global_a` inside `libfoo.so` (the `global_a` inside `libfoo.so` is still a 4-byte `int`, but now gets 8 byte `double` written into it).

> Valgrind in either case has no shown errors.

Valgrind is *exceptionally* weak in checking globals, and almost never complains about them. You should get into the habit of checking your programs with `gcc -fsanitize=address` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Would you have any references where I could read up on something like this? As for `-fsanitize`, unfortunately I'm stuck on gcc 4.4.7 (Centos 6) so that's unavailable for me.